# What is the relation with gauss-seidel relaxation in D3.js code?

Tags: javascript, math, d3.js

I am learning `D3.js`, I find that [source code here](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/v3.5.17/src/layout/force.js#L79-L95) refers `gauss-seidel relaxation`, I search it and then find the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method). But I cannot figure out the relation of them. Does anybody knows that?

Here is just the copy of code:

```
// gauss-seidel relaxation for links
for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
  o = links[i];
  s = o.source;
  t = o.target;
  x = t.x - s.x;
  y = t.y - s.y;
  if (l = (x * x + y * y)) {
    l = alpha * strengths[i] * ((l = Math.sqrt(l)) - distances[i]) / l;
    x *= l;
    y *= l;
    t.x -= x * (k = (s.weight + t.weight ? s.weight / (s.weight + t.weight) : 0.5));
    t.y -= y * k;
    s.x += x * (k = 1 - k);
    s.y += y * k;
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your question, actually? Although it's an interesting issue well worth digging into it I am afraid it is not well suited for SO for several reasons. Can you narrow it down? I guess, there is no actual problem with the code, right?

Comment: @altocumulus yeah, I just want to theory, I know `gauss-seidel relaxation` is used to solve `system of linear equations`, but I can't see what's the `system of linear equations`here

Comment: It's the system of linear equations determining the **link distances/forces** between **each pair of nodes**. In the words of the [spec](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Force-Layout.md#linkDistance): *For each tick of the layout, the distance between each pair of linked nodes is computed and compared to the target distance; the links are then moved towards each other, or away from each other, so as to converge on the desired distance.*